# RecordSeperatorPolicy Spring Batch by length / number of characters

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Use Case:
A .dat legacy flat file(File2) with about 2 million records with fixed length continuous though. Need to read that file and in every record there is a unique ID which I need to grab and check against a diff set(File1) of file and remove this record.

What I did ?
I configured 2 jobs. 1st job will read File1 using FixedLengthTokenizer and will grab the unique Ids and write to a diff file on which I configured a tasklet to create indexes using Apache Lucene.

2nd Job is to read the File2, now, this file is a little tricky. There is no delimiter or a record separator. All I know is every record will contain about 1400 characters. I researched a lot and the only hope I have is with this **RecordSeparatorPolicy** which Im not sure how to implement for this usecase.
After reading every record, in the processor I need to search in the indexes created in Job1 and then somehow remove the record in File2.

Where am I struggling ?
So, the output file I need to generate should not touch or transform the original format fo the file. Now, instead of creating a new file using the ItemWriter, is there a way to remove that record in the same file ? My guess is NO.
So, I using the PassThroughLineMapper which is reading the entire file as a single String. It is a 2million record file in which every record has 1400 characters. Java String cannot hold that much either. 
Other thought was, writing a custom ItemReader in which I would use a BufferedReader and somehow break 1400 characters a single line and then send it to the processor. But this wasnt working either.

How do I read this kind of a file ? Also, I didnt want to use any kind of POJOs because I need the file exactly how it is, and I'm not transforming anything.
Please suggest an approach.

Comment: Why didn't your custom reader work? IMO this is the way how you should do it.

Comment: @HansjoergWingeier : Not sure what I was doing wrong, I can post the reader, but do you have an impl in mind ?

Comment: From what I read, I would write my own reader. I don't have special impl in  mind, but I know, that loading the whole input at once is the wrong approach. As far as I understood, you don't have a line separator and not all recoards have the same length, therefore using FlatFileItemReader as-it-is is no option (because it uses BufferedReader.readLine() inside). It should be possible to extend from FlatFileItemReader and overwrite the appropriate methods, though. But please, post your reader code, so that the community  can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [FixedLengthTokenizer](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1FLDB_enFR608FR608&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=FixedLengthTokenizer) class you can use to read your source file. It lets you specify the number of fields and their respective length for each line of your source file.

See also : [Springbatch documentation §6.6.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html).

Here's an example :

```
<bean id="tokenizer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
    <property name="names" value="column1, column2, column3, column4" />
    <property name="columns" value="1-100, 101-349, 350-1000, 1001-1400" />               
</bean>
```

---

**UPDATE**

If your records differ, there is a class `PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer`, which can match multiple types within a single file.

For more informations (and examples) of such an implementation, refer to : [SpringBatch Patterns §11.5 - Multi-Line Records](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html)

Comment: I have used the FixedLengthTokenizer for my first job. However, I think it only works for a fixed length format file in which every line ends with a proper \n . That means every line should be consistent. In my case the file is like the first record line can end at it's 1200th character. The second line can end at nth character of another record. All the 1400 characters are not in a single line. Even for FixedLengthTokeinzer we need to specifiy a LineMapper. If I use a DefaultLinemapper it expects the entire record in a single line. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @PavanSandeep How do you know where the record ends within the line of 1400 characters?

Comment: @PavanSandeep I updated my post with some more informations

Comment: I don't, so all I know is to treat 1400 characters as a record. I don't have a line separator. So, I'm not sure how FixedLengthTokenizer will help me. FixedLengthTokenizer needs a line mapper and if I use a default line mapper then it looks for a new line every record. And thats the reason I was looking at this RecordSeparatorPolicy to see if this helps me separating records.

Comment: @Thrax - Could you please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674370/caused-by-org-springframework-batch-item-file-transform-incorrectlinelengthexce ?